# Automatically save plot and associated code

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I would like to save automatically each generated plot and associated code from a R session in a specific directory.

I noticed that RStudio stores every plots in a temporary file (/tmp/Rtmp*/*.png in Linux). Therefore my .Last function copies all these files in a save directory when I close R. Yet, I would like also to copy the associated code (i.e., ~ the 10 last lines) with these plots in some *.Rhistory files (using savehistory function). The directory would contain something like :

- plot1.png
- .plot1.Rhistory
- plot2.png
- .plot2.Rhistory
- ...

First thing that would help me is to understand how the Rstudio plot function works but I did not find the sources. I assume that it uses dev.copy() as dev.list() outputs is :

```
plot(0)
dev.list()
> RStudioGD       png 
        2         3
```

Have you any ideas?

Edit : Looking at rstudio sources, I found in the Tools.R file a saveGraphicsSnapshot function but I still do not understand how it works ...

Comment: Why would you need this? Can't think of any use case.

Comment: I use to plot plenty of graphs from plenty of databases and often I forget the exact code associated to these graphs :) The idea is thus to keep a backup of my work in R during some days

Answer (score 0):

First of all, RStudio is a front-end for R, so to "understand how the RStudio plot function works" is... just to understand how the R `plot` function works. You can google around to find the documentation.

Now, to the point: The simplest way to output the result of `plot()` to a file is to use the functions listed [here](http://statmethods.net/graphs/creating.html) (By the way, I recommend you take a good look to that site... it's a great learning resource for R). In your code, simply put the relevant function:

```
# A simple example:
x <- rnorm(1000)
pdf('mytestplot.pdf') # This will redirect the output of the plot() function
                      # to a PDF file
hist(x)
dev.off() # This will "turn off" the output "redirecting"... after invoking
          # this function, plots will be shown again in the plot viewer
```

Other functions:

- `png()`: output to PNG file
- `jpeg()`: output to JPEG file
- and so on

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank for your answer but it does not solve my pb: I want to plot graphs interactively with Rstudio that are display in RStudioGD and save in a png file (image+code) at the same time. I hope this is clearer. Moreover Rstudio has some specific fonction .rs.* (e.g., .rs.activateGraphicsDevice)